# Solving quadratic equations in Z/nZ

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is there a general methodology to solve $X^2 = X \:\mathbb{mod}\: n$?

A solution verifies the interesting fact that $X^i = X \:\mathbb{mod}\: n$ for $i>0$.

I think we can't really use discriminant like in algebra, but there may be a theorem answering my question.

Bonus question: 
Same with quadratic forms $X^2 + AX + B = 0 \:\mathbb{mod}\: n$

Comment: $X^2 - X = X(X-1) = 0\:\mathbb{mod}\:n$ So it is equivalent to search for consecutive divisors of $n$

Comment: Chinese Remainder theorem?

Comment: Please explain I am not an expert and don't know all the theorems.